# AVErrorMediaServicesWereReset in AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification

Tags: ios, iphone, avcapturesession

I have a problem with `AVCaptureSession` `startRunning`. It's problem only on iphone 5 with IOS 7. My app should record video and show all on `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, but if I test on iphone 5, first time call error = `AVErrorMediaServicesWereReset`.
This is my code, where I create capturemanager and `startRunning`:

```
    -(void)startVideoTranslation{   
    CGRect r = videoBackView.bounds;

    videoPreviewView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:r];
    [videoBackView addSubview:videoPreviewView];

    if (currentGameType == MPGameTypeCrocodile){
        if (captureManager == nil) {
            captureManager = [[AVCamCaptureManager alloc] init];

            [captureManager setDelegate:self];
            if ([captureManager setupSession]) {
                //Create video preview layer and add it to the UI

                AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[captureManager session]];
                CALayer *viewLayer = [videoPreviewView layer];
                [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

                CGRect bounds = [videoPreviewView bounds];
                bounds.origin.y = bounds.origin.y+1;
                [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:bounds];

                if ([newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.connection isVideoOrientationSupported]) {
                    [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
                }

                [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

                [viewLayer insertSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer below:[[viewLayer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]];

                captureVideoPreviewLayer = newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer;


                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(isErrorSession:) name:AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification object:nil];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
                        [[captureManager session] startRunning];
                    });
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this selector I call here:

```
-(void)showPrepareView{
[self playSound:@"start"];

BGView.frame = videoBackView.bounds;

[prepareView addSubview:videoBackView];
[self startVideoTranslation];
[videoBackView addSubview:BGView];
```

In this code I use `AVAudioPlayer` in `[self playSound:]`,
on `videobackView` i add my `PreviewLayer`.

Does anyone know the reason for this problem?

Now,I solve this problem so, I move in -(id)initWithFrame:

```
captureManager = [[AVCamCaptureManager alloc] init];
[captureManager setDelegate:self]
[captureManager setupSession];
[[captureManager session] startRunning];
```

But I don't understand what is it.